# fetch and get requests URL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to get information with a fetch (client) and a get (server) requests to get data from the server with the client and printing it.
for some reason I can't get the information I'm looking for and I think it has somthing to do with the url I'm entering, can I get an explanation, or maybe an example about the url I'm supposed to enter?

I'll enter my code as an example:

client:

```
//bitcoin page: url - 'http://localhost:3000/bitcoin'
//NOTE: the proxy is: 'http://localhost:3001'
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function BitCoin() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  console.log("entered bitcoin page");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("NOT SURE WHAT TO WRITE HERE")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{textAlign:"center", fontFamily:"Comic Sans MC", fontSize:"100"}}>
      THIS IS THE BitCoin PAGE

      <nav>
        <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
      </nav>

      <nav>
        <Link to="/coins"> Coins </Link>
      </nav>

      <p>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BitCoin;
```

server:

```
//index.js: url - 'http://localhost:3001'
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();

app.get('NOT SURE WHAT TO WRITE HERE', (req, res) => {

  console.log("entered bitcoin query!");

  let msg = "";

//some functions to get the msg I'm looking for (not relevant)

  res.json({ message: msg });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

as you can see there's a log when entering the get request but the console's not logging it, I'm guessing the client and the server are not communicating and that's what makes the problem.

thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the general architecture of your technology stack:

- You have the React frontend running under `http://localhost:3000`. This is simply serving the React app through a development server on your computer.
- Additionally, you have a NodeJS app (using express) running at `http://localhost:3001`. Notably, this runs under a different port to the React app.

In your express code, you would define a url which the React frontend can call, to fetch data. So let's call it `/coin-message`:

```
app.get('/coin-message', (req, res) => {
```

Now, in the React app, you can make ajax requests to this url:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3001/coin-message")
```

Note that you need to include the full URL and port in the `fetch()` - this is because the Node app runs under a different port.

**Important**

Because you want to make ajax requests to a URL which has a different port to the React app, you will encounter a [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) problem. This is a security measure activated by browsers to prevent web app vulnerabilities. To solve this, you can use one of the CORS middlewares for express, such as [this one](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

Answer (score 1):

server:

```js
app.get('/bitcoin', ...)
```

client:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3001/bitcoin')
```